# only template Controller

Tags: magento2, layout, template, controllers, admin-controller

I'm working on a module in the admin part but can someone tell me please how I can load just my template from my controller without the admin menu in the left, the title and the footer.

here is one of my secondary controller :

```
<?php
  namespace Mymodule\AdminPage\Controller\Adminhtml\Secondcontroller;

  class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
  {
    /**
    * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
    */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
         parent::__construct($context);
         $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        return  $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    }
  }
?>
```

and there is his the layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>
            Module Mymodule
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template" template="Mymodule_AdminPage::secondary.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code in your `layout.xml` file under `<body>` tag

```
<referenceBlock name="page.menu" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="footer" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="header" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="logo" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="page.title" remove="true"/>
```

After that you have to override below file

> vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/View/Result/Page.php

inject `\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request` in `__construct` method and add `$this->request = $request;` in `__construct` function

and in this file change `setActiveMenu` function to these

```
public function setActiveMenu($itemId)
{
    $action     = $this->request->getFullActionName();
    if($action != 'yourrouter_controller_action')
    {
        $menuBlock = $this->layout->getBlock('menu');
        $menuBlock->setActive($itemId);
        $parents = $menuBlock->getMenuModel()->getParentItems($itemId);
        foreach ($parents as $item) {
            /** @var $item \Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Item */
            $this->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend($item->getTitle());
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```